# Flask-login on Apache sets user to anonymous after a few clicks and a few page reloads

Tags: python, apache, flask, flask-login

**NOTE**: This issue only appears to happen when I am running Flask with WSGI on Apache. When I run it via `flask run --host=0.0.0.0` I get no issues whatsoever.

I realize that there are many other questions with a similar issue, and I have tried applying the different recommendations, in particular the following:

setting:

```
        login_user(form.user, remember=True, force=True)  # Tell flask-login to log them in.
        session.permanent = True
        app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(seconds=3600)
        session.modified = True
```

As well as: `app.config["REMEMBER_COOKIE_DURATION"] = timedelta(seconds=3600)`.

I am running Flask on Apache 2.4 with Python 3.6.

Here's the code for my app:

```
import sys
import os
import os.path
import ssl
import json
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from flask import Flask, make_response, url_for, render_template, jsonify, redirect, request, session
from flask_ldap3_login import LDAP3LoginManager
from flask_login import LoginManager, login_user, logout_user, UserMixin, current_user
from flask_security import login_required
from flask_session import Session
from flask_ldap3_login.forms import LDAPLoginForm
from ldap3 import Tls

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret'
app.config['DEBUG'] = True

# Hostname of your LDAP Server
app.config['LDAP_HOST'] = 'dc.website.com'

# Port number of your LDAP server
app.config['LDAP_PORT'] = 636

# Specify the server connection should use SSL
app.config['LDAP_USE_SSL'] = True

# Base DN of your directory
app.config['LDAP_BASE_DN'] = 'CN=Users,DC=website,dc=com'

# Users DN to be prepended to the Base DN
app.config['LDAP_USER_DN'] = ''

# Groups DN to be prepended to the Base DN
app.config['LDAP_GROUP_DN'] = ''

# The RDN attribute for your user schema on LDAP
app.config['LDAP_USER_RDN_ATTR'] = 'cn'

# The Attribute you want users to authenticate to LDAP with.
app.config['LDAP_USER_LOGIN_ATTR'] = 'sAMAccountName'

# The Username to bind to LDAP with
app.config['LDAP_BIND_USER_DN'] = 'CN=LDAP Read-only,CN=Users,DC=website,dc=com'

# The Password to bind to LDAP with
app.config['LDAP_BIND_USER_PASSWORD'] = 'password'

app.config["REMEMBER_COOKIE_DURATION"] = timedelta(seconds=3600)

login_manager = LoginManager(app)              # Setup a Flask-Login Manager
ldap_manager = LDAP3LoginManager(app)          # Setup a LDAP3 Login Manager.

# Initialize a `Tls` context, and add the server manually. See
# http://ldap3.readthedocs.io/ssltls.html for more information.
tls_ctx = Tls(
    validate=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
    version='ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1.3',
    ca_certs_file='/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/cert.crt',
    valid_names=[
        'dc.website.com',
    ]
)

ldap_manager.add_server(
    app.config.get('LDAP_HOST'),
    app.config.get('LDAP_PORT'),
    app.config.get('LDAP_USE_SSL'),
    tls_ctx=tls_ctx
)

# Create a dictionary to store the users in when they authenticate
# This example stores users in memory.
users = {}


# Declare an Object Model for the user, and make it comply with the
# flask-login UserMixin mixin.
class User(UserMixin):
    def __init__(self, dn, username, data):
        self.dn = dn
        self.username = username
        self.data = data

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.dn

    def get_id(self):
        return self.dn


# Declare a User Loader for Flask-Login.
# Simply returns the User if it exists in our 'database', otherwise
# returns None.
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    if id in users:
        return users[id]
    return None


# Declare The User Saver for Flask-Ldap3-Login
# This method is called whenever a LDAPLoginForm() successfully validates.
# Here you have to save the user, and return it so it can be used in the
# login controller.
@ldap_manager.save_user
def save_user(dn, username, data, memberships):
    user = User(dn, username, data)
    users[dn] = user
    return user


# Declare some routes for usage to show the authentication process.
@app.route('/')
def home():
    # Redirect users who are not logged in.
    if not current_user or current_user.is_anonymous:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))

    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    # Instantiate a LDAPLoginForm which has a validator to check if the user
    # exists in LDAP.
    form = LDAPLoginForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # Successfully logged in, We can now access the saved user object
        # via form.user.
        login_user(form.user, remember=True, force=True)  # Tell flask-login to log them in.
        session.permanent = True
        app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(seconds=3600)
        session.modified = True
        return redirect('/')  # Send them home

    return render_template('login.html', form=form, current_user=current_user)

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('login'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

And here's the WSGI file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6

import logging
import sys
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0, '/opt/flaskapp/')
from flaskapp import app as application
application.secret_key = 'secret'
```

Sometimes the user gets logged out after a few seconds, other times the session can last an hour. When I check the browser's memory (in Firefox, Chrome and Edge) the session cookies are still there.

Am I doing something wrong? I've also tried checking whether or not the `users` array becomes empty. It does. Even if I make some kind of a `try` check before the line `users = {}`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the WSGI file, as it is Apache that handles the sessions.

The line `app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(seconds=3600)` from the application code should actually be in the WSGI file, so that it should look like this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3.6

import logging
import sys
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0, '/opt/flaskapp/')
from flaskapp import app as application
application.secret_key = 'secret'
application.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(seconds=3600)
```